# How to verify if every object in an array of objects has some keys

Tags: mocha.js, bdd, rethinkdb, chai

I'm using the chai expect library for my tests. I have an array of objects which is the test data. Each object has 2 properties `name` and `profession`. I inject these into a table. When I retrieve all records from the get the same array back, but now every object in the array has been added with an auto generated `id` field. I need to verify my test data against the retrieved data. Is there any shorthand way of doing this in chai without having to iterate through the retrieved data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `without` to eliminate a field in result:

```
r.table('test').without('id')
```

THat way you can assert against it easily.

Example code:

```
var chai   = require('chai')
var assert = chai.assert

var r      = require('rethinkdb')

r.connect({
   host: 'localhost',
       port: 28015,
  })
  .then(function(conn) {
    return conn
  })
  .then(function(conn) {
    return r.table('table').without('id').run(conn)
  })
  .then(function(cursor) {
    return cursor.toArray()
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    assert.deepEqual([
     {name: 'foo', profession: 'bar'},
     {name: 'foo2', profession: 'bar2'},
    ], data)
  })
```